# call API to change order of the array in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am having an array of objects like this. I need to send an API request to the database to change their display order. How can I pass `order_position` into the body of an API request? I intend to send an API request after clicking the confirm button. Should I send an API request every time the up and down arrows are pressed? Please help me, this problem is really hard for me

```
getFolders() {
    let data: any[] = [
      {
        id: 100,
        name: '店舗',
        order_position: 1
      },
      {
        id: 101,
        name: '東日本統括部',
        order_position: 2
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        name: '東日本統',
        order_position: 3
      }
    ]
    this.list_folders = data
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would like to use vue-draggable, probably you can try this way

1. use vue-draggable to rearrange element's order
2. whenever you drag an item it will trigger an event 'change'(@change)
3. there you can rearrange the order_position property with the index
4. send the whole array to backend and update with id or ( truncate and reinsert)
   hope this may help you